# Permission denied ipython_genutils

Tags: jupyter-notebook, permission-denied

I am trying to install jupyter notebook on my Ubuntu, but there was an error and I cannot fix it. Many thanks if anyone can help.

The complain is below:

```
Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipython_genutils'
 shaoshuai@shaoshuai-ThinkPad-T420:~$ pip install ipython_genutils
   Collecting ipython_genutils
   Using cached ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: ipython-genutils
Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
   File "/home/shaoshuai/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipython_genutils'

Comment: what command did you run? did you use sudo? looks like you tried without the required privilege. "permission denied"

Comment: Is this programming related? There are other pages in the stackexchange network that seem more suitable for this (http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: thanks guys, i reinstalled it under root and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages is best done using root privileges, but in favor of the user.
This is done using:

```
sudo -H pip install *package*
```